# Не могу получить доступ к строке "ttt", выходит ошибка "The method ttt() is undefined for the type NameGamer"

Tags: java

```
package user;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.*;

public class Create {
  public static void main(String[] Args) {
    NameGamer t = new NameGamer("Андрей", 18);
    NameGamer.setCar();
    NameGamer.setModel();
    NameGamer.nameChange();
    NameGamer.setName();
    NameGamer.setCarAge();
  }
}

class NameGamer {
  private static String name;
  //выбор автомобиля из предоставленного выбора и проверка на правильность написания кода

  //ввод данных проверка на совершеннолетие
  private int age;

  NameGamer(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    if (age < 18) {
      System.out.println("Вы не достигли совершеннолетия");
    }
  }

  static String setCar() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Выберите марку автомобиля Volvo или Audi");
    String result = null;
    if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      result = sc.nextLine();
    } else {
      System.out.println("Ошибка");
    }
    switch (result) {//выбор модели с помощью switch
      case "Volvo":
        System.out.println("Выберите модель XC60 или XC40");
        return "Volvo";
      case "Audi":
        System.out.println("Выберите модель A4 или A3 ");
        return "Audi";
      default:
        System.out.println("Повторите ввод");
        return setCar();
    }
  }

  static String setModel() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    java.lang.String ttt = new String();
    ttt = sc.nextLine();
    switch (ttt) {
      case "XC60":
        System.out.println("Volvo XC60");
        return "XC60";
      case "XC40":
        System.out.println("Volvo XC40");
        return ttt = "Volvo XC40";
      case "A4":
        System.out.println("Audi A4");
        return ttt = "Audi A4";
      case "A3":
        System.out.println("Audi A3");
        return ttt = "Audi A3";
      default:
        System.out.println("Неккоректный ввод, введите заново");
        return setModel();
    }
  }

  /*изменение имении, проверка кода на пустую строку,
  дальнейшее присваивание введенных данных к строке name из сеттера
  */
  static void nameChange() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String r;
    do {
      System.out.println("Введи : Изменить имя");
      r = sc.nextLine();
    } while (!(r.equals("Изменить имя")));
  }

  static void setName() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите новое имя");
    String d = sc.nextLine();
    name = d;
    System.out.println("Теперь ваше имя: " + name);
  }

  static void setCarAge() {
    if (ttt().contains("Volvo XC60")) {
      System.out.println("fff");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт! На будущее: старайтесь убирать не имеющий отношения к проблеме код из вопроса. Методы `setCar`, `setModel` и им подобные сложностей не вызывают и из примера их можно безболезненно убрать, так Вы сэкономите время отвечающим и быстрее получите ответ. Сейчас лишний код не помешал @Komdosh ответить на вопрос, но в дальнейшем это может привести к закрытию вопроса. Почитайте [что такое МСВП и как его создать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Вы почему-то вызываете `ttt` как функцию, причём пытаетесь обратиться к ней когда она является локальной для метода `setModel`, скорее всего вам необходимо её объявить как статическую переменную класса `NameGamer`.

```
class NameGamer {
  private static String ttt = new String();
}
```

и избавиться от объявления таковой в методе `setModel`

```
java.lang.String ttt = new String();
```

Тогда метод будет компилироваться

```
static void setCarAge() {
  if (ttt.contains("Volvo XC60")) {
    System.out.println("fff");
  }
}
```

Однако, у вас видимо возникнут дополнительные проблемы из-за недостаточного понимания различий статического класса и экземпляра класса. Когда вы создаёте объект, это не то же самое, что и изменение статический полей класса. Таким образом та же переменная `private int age;` не будет видна в статических методах класса `NameGamer`

```
static void setCarAge() {
  int compilationError = age; // Вызовет ошибку компиляции, так как переменная age будет принадлежать только экземпляру класса.

  //другой код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло